# Access table cell values within Google Groups Member page using Watir

Tags: html, google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver, google-groups

I am looking to access table data within a webpage that seems to be harder to reach than other methods I've seen posted.  I am concerned that some of the HTML is visible to Watir because if you save the page as an HTML file, the table and its data are not included.

Here's the situation:
Google Groups has a member list (when you are viewing the settings as a Group admin).  I want to find (or iterate) through the table, looking to match an email address.  When that is found, I would select the row (checkbox), which enables the 'Actions' menu.  From the actions menu, I would update the Delivery settings to 'No email'.

I've attached a screenshot of the members page as well as a snippet of the HTML.

Please post suggestions/answers specific to Google Groups tables.  I've tried 6+ other approaches that work on simpler HTML pages, but not on Google Groups.

Thanks

[HTML (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cywn.jpg)

Here's a screenshot of the menu I am trying to access.
[Actions popup menu (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQb81.jpg)

Before and after when click on the 'Actions' menu button to get the hovering menu.

Before

`<div tabindex="0" role="button" class="IVILX2C-n-a jfk-button-standard IVILX2C-k-c" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="gwt-uid-809" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false" data-title="Actions">`

After

`<div tabindex="0" role="button" class="IVILX2C-n-a jfk-button-standard IVILX2C-k-c IVILX2C-n-a-selected IVILX2C-n-j" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="gwt-uid-809" aria-expanded="true" aria-disabled="false" data-title="Actions" aria-activedescendant="gwt-uid-819">`

Note, the "gwt-uid-xxx" value is not consistent between sessions.

Update:  These three lines seem to work to click the 'Actions' menu, hover over 'Change delivery settings', and click 'No email'

`@driver.element(text: 'Actions').click

@driver.element(text: 'Change delivery setting').hover

@driver.div(class: 'popupContent', index: 1).div.div.div(text: 'No email').click`

EDIT:  Code below

```html
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'logger'
require 'csv'

def setup
  @driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

  # set the timeout for implicit waits
  @driver.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5

  #Create log file
  if @logger.nil?
    @logger = Logger.new( 'D:/Google Drive/_code/GroupsEmailSetting/ChangeDeliverySetting_log.txt',10)
    @logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
    @logger.datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
  end

  #admin credentials
  @login_user = 'someone@else.com'
  @login_pwd = 'pwd!'

end

def teardown
  puts "Enter to close"
  a = gets.chomp
  @driver.quit
  @logger.close
end

def run
  setup
  yield
  teardown
end

run do

  @driver.goto "https://accounts.google.com"
  element = @driver.text_field(:id => "Email")
  element.send_keys(@login_user)
  @driver.button(:id => "next").click
 
  element = @driver.text_field(:id => "Passwd")
  element.send_keys(@login_pwd)
  @driver.button(:id => "signIn").click

  @logger.info "User logged in: #{@user}"


  #TEMP # find users, change email setting
  @domain = 'domain.com'
  @group = 'watir_table'
  @user = 'someone@else.com'
  @dsetting = 'No email'
  @logger.info("Group & User selected: #{@group + "@" + @domain + " : " + @user}")

  #END TEMP
  @driver.goto "https://groups.google.com/a/domain.com/forum/#!managemembers/#{@group}/members/active"


  @logger.info "Group loaded: #{@group}"

  browser.span(text: 'someone@else.com').parent.parent.checkbox.click

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common pattern and it would be nice if we had a better way to address it. Try something like this:

```
[email1, email2, email3].each do |email_address|
    row = @driver.div(text: email_address).parent.parent
    row.checkbox.click
    row.div(text: 'All email').parent.parent.checkbox.click
end

browser.element(text: 'Change delivery setting').hover
browser.element(text: 'No email').click
```

Comment: When I try this: `browser.span(text: 'someone@else.com').parent.parent.checkbox.click` I get `"NameError: undefined local variable or method 'browser'`. When I change "browser" to "@driver", I get `Exception "unable to locate element, using {:text -> "someone@else.com", :tag_name=> "span"}`

Comment: Update your post with your code. If you are using Watir, you need something like: `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`

Comment: I've added my code to the main post.  I do have the command you noted.  So far, my code works up until locating the table or elements within the table.

Comment: Oops, it's a `div` not a `span` I was looking at the other td.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Now that I can locate the email address and checkbox, I need to locate the "Delivery" column.  Ultimately my scripts logic would only check the checkbox for emails that are located AND have a value of 'All email' under "Delivery".  How would I add this condition?  `@driver.div(text: 'someone@else.com').parent.parent.div(text: 'All email').parent.parent.checkbox.click` works, but my final solution will need to iterate over a list, so not sure this is the best approach.

Comment: Also, I'm able to trigger the 'Actions' menu, but not sure how to select 'Change Delivery Settings > No email'.  I've added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: `@driver.element(text: 'Change delivery setting').hover` doesn't seem to work.  I get an Exception "unable to locate element'.  The only change I noticed when hovering over the menu is a DIV element change.  See my post for the before and after.  Thanks.

Comment: One more thing to add - I was able to get HOVER to work, but I had to use  `@driver.element(text: 'Actions').click` before.  But, even when that working, when get to the 'No email' command, it clicks the first in the table, not the value in the sub-menu.

Comment: Looks like this sequence works.  `@driver.element(text: 'Actions').click
  
@driver.element(text: 'Change delivery setting').hover

@driver.div(class: 'popupContent', index: 1).div.div.div(text: 'No email').click`